# Append distributed child to <content> element in Polymer

Tags: dom, polymer, shadow-dom

I have a simple Polymer element:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">


<dom-module id="observing-test">
  <template>
    <p>This is the title:</p>
    <content id="top" select="#title"></content>
    <p>This is the content:</p>
    <content id="bottom" select="#content"></content>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer( {
      is: 'observing-test',

      ready: function(){
        console.log("Ready!");

        Polymer.dom( this.$.top ).observeNodes( function( info ) {
          console.log(" TOP CHANGED!", info );
        });

        Polymer.dom( this.$.bottom ).observeNodes( function( info ) {
          console.log(" BOTTOM CHANGED!", info );
        });
      },

      attached: function(){
        console.log("Attached!");
        OT = this;
      }

    })
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Basic usage:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="The basic page">
  <meta name="author" content="Tony Mobily">
  <title>The title</title>
  <link rel="import" href="test-component.html">
</head>

<body>

<observing-test>
  <div id="title"><p>TITLE!</p></div>
  <div id="content"><p>CONTENT!</p></div>
</observing-test>

</body>
```

Right now, anything added to either `#top` or `#bottom` is observed.

So, how do I append a child to the `#top` `<content>` element so that the observer gets triggered?

If I reach the element from the local DOM (from console): `MAYBE = Polymer.dom( OT ).children[0]` (this will be `<div id="title">`, and then `Polymer.dom( MAYBE ) .appendChild( document.createElement( 'p' ) )`, the new element gets added to the `<div>`. However, the observer doesn't get triggered (because I am adding a child to the `<div>` rather than the `<div>`'s parent, which I assume is what is being watched.)

So questions:

- When observing a `<content>` element in the local DOM, how can then *append* or *delete* a node from there? Basically, I want to add an extra child element to a `<content>` one, so that `OT.getContentChildren('#top')` returns one extra element
- When observing, will I ever get notified for changes made *directly* to one of the node's children? Grand-children's modifications don't bubble up, right? What do I *actually* observe when targeting a `<content>` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also posting my own answer, which was made possible by Vincent's (thanks!)

If you have an element like this:

```
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <dom-module id="observing-test">
      <template>
        <p>This is the list of lines:</p>
        <content id="c" select=".line"></content>
      </template>

      <script>
        Polymer( {
          is: 'observing-test',

          ready: function(){
            console.log("Ready!");

            Polymer.dom( this.$.c ).observeNodes( function( info ) {
              console.log("CHANGED!", info );
            });
          },

          attached: function(){
            console.log("Attached!");
            // GLOBAL, so that we can play we it in the console
            OT = this;
          }

        })
      </script>
    </dom-module>
```

Keep in mind that the composite DOM is the result of the local DOM, with `<content>` tags resolved.
So, in order to "add" element to what's placed in lieu of  a `<content>` element with a `select`, you need to add elements to the light DOM that will match the `<content>`'s selection.
For example if your page contains:

```
<observing-test>
  <p>Some content</p>
  <p class="line">Moved line 1</p>
  <p class="line">Moved line 2</p>
  <hr>
  <p class="line">Moved line 3</p>
</observing-test>
```

If you then create an element:

```
p = document.createElement('p')
p.appendChild(   document.createTextNode('text')   )
p.className = 'line'
```

And add it to the light DOM:

```
Polymer.dom( OT ).appendChild( p )
```

The observer on the `<content>` element gets triggered.
Note that you *must* assign the class before hand. If you do:

```
p = document.createElement('p')
p.appendChild(   document.createTextNode('text')   )
```

And then you append the child:

```
Polymer.dom( OT ).appendChild( p )
```

And only *then* you add the right class to the element:

```
p.className = 'line'
```

The callback doesn't get triggered.

The original question didn't really "work" because the filter was based on an ID. So, only one element is ever going to match -- and therefore get selected by `<content>`.

Answer (score 1):

- `<content>` is a DOM insertion point (I won't try to explain in detail what it is, [Polymer's dev guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#dom-distribution) does it better than me). Basically, every light DOM child of your component that matches the `select` query of a `<content>` node will be inserted inside it.

  So to insert another child in a `<content>` node, you have to add a child that matches it's `select` query to your component's light DOM.

  To do that, you should change the `select` queries to target something else than IDs (i.e class or attributes), like so:

In your element's dom-module :

```
 <content id="top" select=".title"></content>
```

Usage :

```
 <observing-test id="ot">
   <p class=".title">TITLE!</p>
   <div id="content"><p>CONTENT!</p></div>
 </observing-test>

 var newTitleNode = document.createElement( 'p' );
 newTitleNode.className = "title";
 Polymer.dom( this.$.ot ).appendChild( newTitleNode );
```

- Polymer's `observeNodes` is used to detect the addition/removal of a node in a local DOM insertion point. What you are doing here is appending a node to a light DOM node that was itself inserted in a `content` insertion point, you are not directly inserting another node. I believe that is why you do not get notified.

Hopefully that helps you, somebody somewhere can probably explain this much better than I do.